# Determine the count of rows returned

Tags: sql, oracle

Okay so i have been trying to find out if its possible to return how many times a particular bit of data is returned

```
Event_id
---------
Change
Change
Change
Problem
Task
```

so i want to find out how many times this string data is returned and pop out a value say for change i would expect 3 and so on.

i was hoping this would be possible in a where statement but i have never used count so unsure on how it all works.

Comment: please have some time to check this https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp

Comment: Please include a [MRE]. Particularly some context about the situation where you are trying to get the `COUNT` and how you want to use it. You will get very different answers if you are trying: to output the result in a query where you just want to `COUNT` each distinct item; to a query when you want to return the rows unchanged with a `COUNT` added in another column; to if you are trying to use the `COUNT` in a filter in the `WHERE` clause within a query; to if you already have a result set in a `CURSOR` and you are trying to get a `COUNT` in PL/SQL (or any other language).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a *classic* `count` function which requires `group by` clause; it should contain all non-aggregated columns (`event_id` in this case).

```
select event_id, 
       count(*)
from your_table
group by event_id
```